# How do I beat the Alliance boss trial

Tags: magicka-2

In the alliance boss trial, you have to face 3 enemies plus backup. The trial requires you to destroy them in less than 30s.

The King seems highly vulnerable to fire beam, so he can be dispatch quite easily. However, I struggle with the other two (queen and magister).

What are they vulnerable to? Is there a quick way to dispatch of them as well?

Answer (score 1):

What difficulty are you talking about? It probably doesn't matter but I'm kinda curious.

For the queen, try to avoid attacking her with your magicks. She has some attack thingy that throws your magicks on the floor for you to have to pick up. If you are playing single player, I'd recommend using the Dragon Strike or whatever it's called first thing. The king can easily be beaten with fire and death but maybe that's because I have the Staff of Helviti (i think it's called) that you can find in the snowy highlands a little ahead of where you fight the war-troll i think. It'll be on the left side, then use the corresponding elements. King's no biggie. Now comes the part where I can't beat. Try to focus on the archer backup people. They can one-hit me. The queen seems to have no weakness that I've found so far, but the reinforcements don't seem to like cold. For the other one, I don't know as I don't focus on him as much as the queen. If you happen to find out how to do this, please tell me! I'll see if I can find more about these guys...

In summary: Target king first. Use death fire beam on king and maybe queen. Use dragon strike or whatever at the very start to get a head start kinda. Use staff of Helviti Look out for archer reinforcements. Reinforcements don't like cold too much. Tell me if you find anything. I'll keep looking.

Also what robe are you using? You may be using a bad robe for this trial.

Hope I could help at least a little!!!

EDIT:: Use the spell thunder spell a lot. They don't like lightning... The thunder spell should be pretty much memorized cause you're probably gonna need it a lot. Fire Fire Death Lightning Lightning I think (I just unlocked it and haven't memorized it.)

Answer (score 1):

Leave the king. He wont attack and at the end he'll run if you beat everyone else. The queen and the human and elf reinforcements are weak to thunder, so I like spamming local storm (FFSAA) as fast as possible. I have no idea how I'm gonna beat the magister in absurd difficulty in under a minute, because his only weaknesses are apparently cold and ice, and those elements suck. If you're willing to sacrifice some speed, use the rock shield to prevent damage from the reinforcements, who all attack physically. Haste should be bound to 2 automatically so try to use that if you're in a pinch. Anyone with a good dwarf killing strategy is welcome to contribute.